# Ignorar ciertos archivos para subir a Github

Tags: git, github, gitignore

Como puedo evitar que se suban este tipos de archivos, que se encuentran en múltiples directorios.
Tengo configurado el .gitignore de la siguiente manera, pero no logro que se descarten esos archivos.

```
#vim backups
*.swp
*.un~
*~
* ~
* .js~
* .py~
.js~
.py~
.swp
.un~
.json~
```

Son archivos que genera Gvim cuando edito los archivos respectivos.
Estos son los archivos que quiero evitar que se suban.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo general terminan en "~" , ".swp", ".un",".py~", etc.

Comment: Es raro que no te los ignore el .gitignore. ¿Has hecho `git add .gitignore` con este contenido?

Comment: Si los archivos ya están siendo _ẗracked_ (a grandes rasgos, si forman parte de la ultima revision), el `.gitignore` no tiene efecto sobre ellos. Es ese el caso? Qué te dice `git status` sobre ellos?

Comment: ¿Porqué en vez de ignorar tan selectivamente, mejor cambias el directorio en el que *vim* o *gvim* guarda los archivos temporales y de intercambio? Por ejemplo, podrías hacer algo como lo siguiente: `set backupdir=/tmp//` para los archivos de *backup*, luego `set directory=/tmp//` para los archivos de intercambio y por último `set undodir=/tmp//` para los archivos de deshacer. Así *vim* no usará el espacio de trabajo para guardar esta información. Saludos

Comment: Bueno cuando comenzé a subir mi proyecto no estaba ignorando estos archivos, y según lo que me dice @eftshift0, si estos ya estaban en mi repositorio, no se evitarían estos archivos. Creo que optaré por la opción cambiar el directorio de estos archivos.

Comment: Deberías hacer `git rm --cached` para dejar de seguir estos ficheros, sin eliminarlos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

si ya forman parte del proyecto, *idealmente* deberías enmendar las revisiones donde agregaste esos archivos para que no queden en la historia (las maravillas de git) pero implica *reescribir* la historia del proyecto... y tiene un precio (no monetario, sino de esfuerzo para ti y las personas que trabajen contigo en el proyecto). Lo que la mayor parte de la gente hace es simplemente borrar los archivos del proyecto (ya con el .gitignore ajustado, para que no se vuelvan a agregar) así:

```
git rm --cached un-archivo
```

Con eso el archivo va a seguir en tu `árbol de trabajo`, por si lo quieres, pero cuando hagas commit ya no va a estar en la nueva revisión y entonces el `.gitignore` si los afectará y no los volverás a ver al hacer status o add o cosas así (a menos que regreses a una revisión anterior a este punto, claro está).

La opción de modificar vi para que escriba los archivos temporales es buena, pero eso no quita que debas aliminar los archivos del proyecto.... al fin y al cabo, ese ajuste es *tuyo*, si yo (o algún otro) clonara ese proyecto, esos archivos que no deberían formar parte del proyecto van a venir.... no está bien.